# How to view TCL REST Response headers

Tags: rest, tcl

My code sample was

```
package require rest
set yweather(forecast) {
   url http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss
   req_args { p: }
   opt_args { u: }
}
rest::create_interface yweather
```

Output

```
% set res [yweather::forecast -p 94089]
channel {title {content {Yahoo! Weather - Sunnyvale, CA}} .........
```

But i am trying to view Response header, like Status codes, set-cookie information. I don't know how to view, some one please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically with handling REST, I'd just use the standard `http` package directly (or wrapped into a little class). That would let you use `http::meta` to get at the gory response details, and also let you control much more precisely what message gets sent in the first place (usually rather important!)

However, that's *me* (as I'm pretty *au fait* with REST and the `http` package). Let's dig into the [`rest` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.html) more carefully and get it to do what we want.

By close reading of the documentation, I see that the interface descriptor dictionary allows the keys `pre_transform` and `post_transform`, and that the `http` token is available in the calling context. Let's try with the `post_transform`…

```
package require rest
set yweather(forecast) {
    url http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss
    req_args { p: }
    opt_args { u: }
    post_transform extract_metadata
}
rest::create_interface yweather
proc extract_metadata {response} {
    upvar 1 token token
    lappend response [http::meta $token]
    return $response
}
```

Now, if you do:

```
set res [yweather::forecast -p 94089]
```

You should get the extra information you want (and far more probably!) in the `meta` field at the end.

Comment: And if you can spot how to do this from simply reading the `rest` package documentation, you're _good_ as those docs are confusing, badly formatted and, in places, flat wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Donal, Is http package support put and delete methods also?, If yes could you explain with an example.

Comment: @Malli Sure it does. Use the [`-method` option to `http::geturl`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M21) in the obvious way. I've got [code online](https://github.com/myGrid/taverna-server/blob/2.5-branch/src/clients/tcl/taverna2server.tcl) but it's a bit tangled up in what I was doing with it. :-)